# Constituent should be a bronze badge on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, moderator-election

I know there is [a post about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143485/312067) on Meta Stack Exchange. But, if you look at [the top voted answer there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143490/312067), it talks about how rare that badge is.

The issue is it is not a rare badge on Stack Overflow at all ([link to badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974/constituent)). More than 100k people already received it and probably 30k+ badge will be awarded during the [next four days](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1). I am not sure about other sites, but it is not a silver badge on Stack Overflow by any means.

I suggest that we make it a bronze badge on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The rarity of the badge doesn't have much to do with it.  There are some silver badges which are *very* uncommon to see (looking at [Research Assistant](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1656/research-assistant) as a *prime* example), and it has a relatively low bar of entry.

The main thing that I see with this particular badge being awarded at Silver instead of Bronze is for a few reasons.

- Bronze badges have to do with general functions/achievements concerning *basic* usage of the site.
- Bronze badges are meant to introduce the user to common features and functionality, and thus are awarded more often overall.
- Silver badges have to do with more advanced functions and achievements, and can require a fair bit of work to obtain.
- Silver badges aren't introductory; they require effort and planning to achieve.

Not to mention, elections *do* require some effort on the part of the voter to (hopefully) vet who they want as a community moderator.

Comment: I found it reasonable. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

I disagree. I think it's rather difficult to earn this badge, because elections don't happen very often. Also, the fact that over 100k people already earned it doesn't make it the most frequently awarded silver badge—for example the [Notable Question badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/27/notable-question) has been awarded 1.4m times.

Comment: Also consider that It is really hard to post a Notable Question these days. But getting Constituent is as easy as one click!

Comment: @Arashsoft "getting Constituent is as easy as one click" If there's an election currently, then yes. If not, you may have to wait even a year for the next election, and during that time you can post numerous Notable Questions.

Comment: Also, you need 150 reputation to vote in an election.

Comment: @Arashsoft: "*Also consider that It is really hard to post a Notable Question these days.*" No, it's not.